# Castlevania-style data visualization

Tags: open-source, data-visualization, user-interface, svg

I need to display the status of a system under test, and thought it would be fun to make it look like a Castlevania 1 map, similar to this:

[image]

In the original Castlevania game, the level you were on was represented by a small animation in one of the red areas. I'd like to do something similar, and **would like recommendations on technologies to use for such a visualization**.

REQUIREMENTS:

- Viewable from a browser
- 2D static background map with dynamic 2D sprites overlayed
- Would update on a regular schedule (once per second?) based on the state of a .yml file (or similar) describing the state of the system under test
- User interface will display additional detailed information to be displayed by clicking on the overlay sprites
- programatic modifications of 2D sprites (examples: make jiggle, make grow and shrink, change color) should be easy to do
- Open Source/Free:beer solutions greatly preferred

The idea would be to allow a room of people observing a test to watch in near real time to better understand test results that have historically been dense text dumps.

Before I start recreating wheels, are there any existing frameworks that already meet my requirements?

Thanks!